# UIPickerView subclass in Swift : error optional value in viewForRow

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uipickerview

I would like to subclass UIPickerView in order to create a custom DatePicker. I tried this, but there is an error in Swift saying :

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on this line : `(view.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel).text = array[row]`

Here is the code :

```
class MyPickerView : UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{

    let array = ["one", "two", "three"]
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }

    //components / row
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    //view for row
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
        if view == nil {
            var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 150,50))
            let label = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0,0, 80, 40))
            label.tag = 1
            view.addSubview(label)
        }
        (view.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel).text = array[row]
        return view
    }
    //did select row
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        println("has selected row \(row)")
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known bug in UIPickerView (started in iOS 7 I think), that the views are never reused. To fix your problem, get rid of the if clause (then there's no need for the tag),

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
    var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 150,50))
    let label = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0,0, 80, 40))
    view.addSubview(label)
    label.text = array[row]
    return view
}
```

The reason you get the error, is because you have two different objects called "view". The one you create inside the if clause is not visible outside that clause, so the "view" you're calling viewWithTag on is the view that's passed in to the method, and that one is always nil.

Comment: Thank rdelmar, yes actually it worked if the var is outside the closure, but the view in parameter is actually always nil as you said. Could I ask why `return array[count]` in `titleForRow...` returns a compiler error : `(Range<!>) -> I.Distance is not convertible to Int` ?

Comment: @Paul, That's not correct syntax. You want array.count. Also, are you implementing titleForRow? You shouldn't be when you implement viewForRow.

Comment: argh, I made a mistake, I wanted to write array[row]. Yes, thanks for the advice I was trying one or the other, perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First you check if view is nil, but after the closure you try to access it whether it's nil or not. If I understood your intention correctly, you should replace

```
var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 150,50))
```

with

```
view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 150,50))
```

because at the moment you are creating a new variable called view within the scope of if statement.

Comment: actually you are right, it works if I create a mView = ... before the closure....edit: but the view in parameter is always nil. Which seems to be a bug as said in the post from rdelmar